# "Real" wheel diameter

Tags: tire

I have a 1983 Bianchi Bici 4, which I long ago converted into my errand bike, and the only one I'll lock up anywhere. 
It's got 32C tires on it right now, but they only just barely fit in the frame with a bit of coaxing. The chain stays are about 3/16 away from the sidewalls, so I'm ok if the wheel is true. The problem is that the top of the tread is incredibly close to the bottom of the brake, as well as the clamp on the changer. Too close, in fact.

So, are there any 32C tires that will result in a slightly smaller overall wheel diameter when inflated? Montreal roads are notoriously bad, and I'd still like to use the fattest tires possible.

The bike was originally equipped with 23s, so clearances are very tight everywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: There isn't really a way of telling if a given tire will be too big as the rim size and other factors can effect the actual inflated size of the tire. Might want to shop around for something in a 28 or 30 if you can find it. A 28 should only be 2mm narrower on each side so you won't really lose that much cushioning.

Comment: Impressive that you got 32 mm tyres on it in the first place - that's a good effort.

Comment: Basically, all tires with a given set of dimension markings on the sidewall will, for a given rim, produce the same actual tire diameter and width, give or take the difference in tread thickness.  The cross section of the tire will tend to be circular, unless the rim is extremely wide or narrow, so the tire is about as "tall" as it is wide.  There are minor variations between manufacturers, but they are pretty much random -- nothing you can count on.

Comment: @DanielRHicks what about the thick layer in some anti puncture tyres? I assume this would have a similar effect on diameter to tread depth

Comment: Racing bikes in 1983 ran on very narrow tyres, 19mm to 21mm was quite standard. So a 32mm might be a bit on the (too) wide side. I'd go for a 25 or even a 23mm.

Comment: 28 sounds perfect for your bike.  Or if it has 27" wheels, then look at dropping to 700c wheels which are ~4mm smaller radius.  Of course that means new tyres anyway.

Comment: Or just think that this is your errand bike, not your speedway screamer.  Just ride it.

Comment: @ChrisH - Yes, thick anti-puncture layers would work about the same as thick tread.  Though how much they add to the top vs the sides is going to depend on some variables.  But in general the OP should avoid such tires if he's really determined to squeeze in a "wide" tire.

Comment: I've got a 28mm and a 32mm Marathon plus on one of my bikes.  I have to check the sidewalls to see which is which and it doesn't seem to make any difference to how the bike rides if I swap them front-to-back.  @Criggie's right

Comment: @ChrisH I've got Marathon Plus 32 on both wheels, but I think maybe I'll swap the rear for a 28. The front wheel is OK, apart from having to thump the wheel to get the tire through the brake pads (even with the quick release open, the old DuraAce EX brakes don't open very wide). A 28 on the rear should do the trick. In fact, I recall now I may have had 28 Conti City Contacts on a few years ago, and they were OK. With the Marathon 32s, some of the tread lugs are just barely kissing the brake and changer bracket. It's been an ongoing challenge for years. Thanks to everyone for the ideas.

Comment: Just as a follow up, I had a Conti 700x32 in the garage (same size as the Marathon), so I put it on. Enormous difference. Easily 1/4" now between the tread and the brake, and also the changer bracket. Also a lot more clearance between the chain stays. So not all 700x32 tires are the same size at all.

Answer (score 5):

Even if someone had a magic database of actual versus nominal sizes for tires, they would need to know what tires you have now and their actual inflated size on your rims to answer.

The best answer is yes, probably there is a nominally 700x32 tire out there that's smaller inflated than what you've got. But, two issues there: tire manufacturers have gotten much, much better than they used to be about accuracy in size labeling, so finding that tire would now be a challenge. Secondly, manufacturers often correct badly size-labeled tires pretty readily, so even if there were a good recommendation out there, it would be a bad question for an SE site since it would be a product recommendation that's highly subject to change.

A better approach may be just get an accurately sized 700x30, which is an existent albeit not super common size.